# Geometry nodes - Geometry disappear after Set Position Node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to project generated plane (**Grid Node**) to mine reflection plane with **Raycast Node**
but geometry disappear after **Set Position Node**.
Also noticed, that Raycast's "Hit normal" socket is **Diamond with Dot**
(which is currently a single value for some reason)

[.blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/91ee8bc0c240457eaa39856df86d3d2a)

> [image: it disappear when raycast hits the reflection plane]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file, thanks.

Comment: @Chris , thanx for your attention! Added blend file to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

just unplug the source position from your raycast node in your uploaded file.

Then it works.

result:

[image]

---

your basic setup was ok. Looks like you made something wrong with your rotation/positioning calculation.

check out this "simple" setup:

[image]

this works. Then i would carefully add an empty just test with translation, if that works, try rotation and so on.

here is the blend file with the simplified setup, but it works ;)

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: ohhh, the main reason of the problem was the Join Geometry node.
For some reason only after it the geometry shows up. Strange behaviour for me